# If a function has nonzero derivative for all $x\in\mathbb R$, it is a homeomorphism of the real line onto its range

Tags: calculus, general-topology, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f '(x) \neq 0$ for every $x$ in $\mathbb R$. Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ onto $f(\mathbb R)$.

I know that homeomorphism can be proved in 3 steps

1. $f$ be bijective,
2. $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, and
3. $f^{-1}$ is continuous on $f(\mathbb R)$

I can't answer ..help me.

Comment: Which parts do you has problem with?

Comment: f be bijective ,how i can proe it??

Comment: Use the mean value theorem: what happens if you have $f(x)=f(y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can already tell $f$ is continuous, since it is differentiable. EDIT:The fact that $f'(x) \neq 0$ guarantees injectivity, by the mean value theorem. 
2) 
Bijection: We  have that $f$ is onto its image, by definition. For injection, try the mean value theorem, by assuming f is not injective, to get a contradiction.3) For continuity of $f^{-1}$ , see what happens with an open set in $\mathbb R_1$ (use $\mathbb R_1$ for domain , and $\mathbb R_2$ for codomain); remember that all intervals are open sets in $\mathbb R$. Notice that for an open interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R_1 $, its image is $(f(a),f(b))$ . Can you see why (remember the intermediate value theorem)?  If $f$ sends $(a,b)$ to $(f(a),f(b))$ , then, what is the preimage of an open set $(f(c),f(d))$ in $f(\mathbb R)$? (I assume here that every map is onto its image, so that $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow f(\mathbb R) $ is onto.

More specifically, continuity of $f^{-1}$ follows from its injectivity: given $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R$, by "bijectiveness" onto its image (which follows from the intermediate value theorem), we have, WOLG, that $f(a,b)=(f(a),f(b))$, so that, by injectivity of $f$, we have that $f^{-1}(a,b)=(f(a),f(b))$ , i.e., the inverse image by $f^{-1}$ of a basic open set is a basic open set.

Comment: Do please explain to me more clearly

Comment: Sure; anything in particular?

Comment: it is easy to prove that f is cont but how i can to prove that f^-1  is cont and f is bijective

Comment: Yes; every differentiable function is continuous.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any follow-ups.

Comment: no i do not have just i have f is differential

Comment: Nitpicking: $f$ may send $(a,b)$ to $\bigl(f(b),f(a)\bigr)$.

Comment: @Michael Hoppe:You're right. Let me edit it. I somehow assumed carelessly $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: You can assume $f'>0$ or $f'<0$ if $f$ is continuously differentiable, but the problem does not state this.

Comment: @nayrb: you're right, but I realized I never actually used that $f'(x)>0$. Injectivity from $f'(x) \neq 0$ is enough. I'll edit to remove that assumption.

Comment: @ruwaida: f is onto its image by construction/definition; notice they're only asking for a bijection to $f(\mathbb R)$ , not to $\mathbb R$. Injectivity follows from the mean value theorem, since $f'(x) \neq 0$. The continuity of the inverse follows from the fact that $f$ is injective, so that $f^{-1}(a,b)=(f(a),f(b))$ , so $f^{-1}$ sends basic open sets to basic open sets.

Comment: Any other comment by the down-voter?